# Ошибка в неопределенной переменной

Tags: python

Ребят, может кто посмотрит свежим взглядом. Не могу найти в чем ошибка.. Ошибка, что неопределенная переменная **add_products** в самом конце цикла while. Если меняю переменную на update_shop, то ошибка пропадает, в файл все равно не записываются продукты которые я ввожу.
модуль берем такой :

**Модуль:**

```
def read_file(file_name):
    file = open (file_name, 'r' , encoding='utf-8')
    message = ''
    for w in file:
        message += w
    return message
```

**Основной код:**

```
import os
from files.store import read_file


shop = {}


def update_shop(dir_name='shop', shop=shop):
    tree = os.walk(dir_name)
    for root, dirs,files in tree:

        for file in files:
            group = read_file('shop/' + file)
            group = group.split(' ')
            
            products = {}
            products.update(zip(group[1::2], group[2::2]))
            shop.update({file:products})
            return shop






def create_message(products):
    message = ''
    for prod, price in products.items():
        message += ' {0}{1} '.format(prod,price)
    return message



def write_to_file(shop=shop):
    
    for group,products in shop.items():
        file_name = 'shop/' + group
        file_group = open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        file_group.write(create_message(products))
        file_group.close()
    else:
        'ошибка'
        return file_name



def add_product(user_group,products,shop=shop):
    if user_group in shop:
        shop[user_group].update(products)
        write_to_file()
        update_shop()

    elif user_group not in shop:
        shop.update({user_group:{}})
        shop[user_group].update(products)
        write_to_file()
    else:
        print ('Error)')





update_shop()

loop = True

while loop:
    group = input('В какой раздел добавим продукты или создадим? \n')
    number = int (input('Сколько видов продуктов будет добавлено в раздел? (напишите числом) \n'))
    i = 1
    products = {}
    while i<= number:
        product = input(' Укажите название продукта, который хотите добавить: ')
        price = int(input('Укажите цену продукта {0} (напишите числом ): ' .format(product)))

        products.update({product:price})

        i+=1

        if i > number:
            add_products(group,products)
            loop = False
```

Comment: отметьте ответ с решением или подтолкнувший к нему галочкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас есть функция `add_product` а вызываете вы `add_products` которой у вас нет. (`s` в конце).
А `update_shop` в принципе не чего в файл не должна писать.

Попробуйте так

```
  if i > number:
            add_product(group,products)
            loop = False
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ошибка, что неопределенная переменная add_products в самом конце цикла
> while. Если меняю переменную на update_shop,

`update_shop` - это у вас вообще-то функция, а не переменная

`add_products`  вы тоже вызываете как функцию

```
add_products(group,products)
```

но в приведённом коде она у вас никак не определена - нет такой функции

если же это у вас кортеж, то тогда надо писать

```
add_products = (group,products)
```

так что вы уж определитесь, что именно вам нужно

Comment: Извините, нашел ошибку)